# Oracle 12c connection configuration errors

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, connectivity, oracle-sql-developer

I've installed Oracle 12c, and I'm trying to create a connexion using SQL Developer but I've got errors.

Here is the parameters after installation and users parameters:

[image]

Like in the photo, the port is 5500 but in `tnsnames.ora` I have this:

```
ORCL =
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

  PDBORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdborcl)
    )
  )
```

The port in here is 1521, so I'm confused which parameters use to create a connexion. It's my first installation of oracle.

[image]

I've changed the port to 1521. Now I've got this error:

> ORA-01017:invalid username/password; logon denied

I changed username to "system". It works on SQL Developer, but on the browser I don't know how to access.

Comment: 5500 is the port used by Databas Express, you can access that in a broswer by using the URL on the screenshot. To connect the database, use the listener port (1521).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following link to access Database Express through the browser:

> https://yourhostname:5500/em

Or

> https://youripaddress:5500/em

Comment: nothing, i'll continue with sql developer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You Oracle 12c Express em will be `https://localhost:5500/em`

You can login in the Browser in this way :-

```
User Name # SYS
Password # SYS User Password
Connect AS # SYSDBA (not NORMAL)
```

I am also attaching the screen shot or Oracle 12c em Express.
[image]

Note :- For Port number will be same in SQL Developer as you have in  `tnsnames.ora` file . In your case it would be `1521`. As already `Mr. Balazs Papp` told you through comments.